# Deploy KIE-CI on Wildfly fails

Tags: maven, drools, wildfly, kie

I am trying to deploy Drools with KIE-CI (for dynamic Maven-packaged rules) on Wildfly 8.0.0.Final.

The POM of my minimalistic test project is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>testprojekt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <drools-version>6.0.1.Final</drools-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Deployment fails with the following errors:

```
11:58:35,430 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."testprojekt-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."testprojekt-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.TypeConverterMap.injector
  at org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.TypeConverterMap.injector(TypeConverterMap.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:289)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:514)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Inject org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.DefaultBeanLocator.autoPublish(Injector)
  at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.DefaultBeanLocator.autoPublish(DefaultBeanLocator.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:289)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:514)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator.validateBeans(ConcurrentValidator.java:76)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:475)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:392)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:93)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    ... 3 more
```

(and some more exceptions like that one)

It works, if I exclude sisu-inject-plexus from the kie-ci dependency like:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.sisu</groupId>
        <artifactId>sisu-inject-plexus</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

But I need that dependency in my "real" project.

Anyone any idea how to get these two (Wildfly and Drools with KIE-CI) working together? And recommendations, where I should file a bugreport?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well ... the resolutions always appear after having searched the second half of the day ...

The problem lies [within the CDI 1.1 specification](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-377). The solution for Wildfly is quite easy, as it is even written [in the WELD documentation](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#4):

> add the following content to `META-INF/jboss-all.xml` of the
>   application
>
> ```
> <jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
>     <weld xmlns="urn:jboss:weld:1.0" require-bean-descriptor="true"/>
> </jboss>
> ```