# Drools will not load with WildFly 14

Tags: maven, wildfly, drools

Trying to upgrade an existing application from Wildfly 10.0.0.Final to WildFly 21.0.0.Final and move it to a container. I'm using Java 11 and the most recent version of Drools (7.46.0.Final). When I boot WildFly 14 or higher, I get the following errors when Drools tries to load:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."example.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."example.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: com.package:example-validation:0.0.1
```

Right before this line, I notice this message in the log:

```
[org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Artifact not fetched from maven: com.package:example-validation:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. To enable the KieScanner you need kie-ci on the classpath
```

What's weird is that I am putting kie-ci on the classpath. Here are the relevant parts of the pom.xml for the child example-validation project:

```
  <packaging>kjar</packaging>
  <artifactId>example-validation</artifactId>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor/>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
          <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
          <version>${drools.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
          <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      ....
  </dependencies>
```

But when I run `mvn clean install` on the child project, I get the following messages:

```
[INFO] Artifact not fetched from maven: org.drools:drools-compiler:7.46.0.Final. To enable the KieScanner you need kie-ci on the classpath
[INFO] Artifact not fetched from maven: org.kie:kie-ci:7.46.0.Final. To enable the KieScanner you need kie-ci on the classpath
```

How do I get kie-ci on the classpath so that I can get kie-ci on the classpath? I see that someone had a similar issue here ([Drools session will not load after Wildfly Upgrade to 19.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62155381/drools-session-will-not-load-after-wildfly-upgrade-to-19-0-0)), but the accepted solution is to upgrade Drools (which I have). Again, this works on Wildfly 10.0.0.Final, so I assume that it is not a problem with our rules since I'm having the same issue with our existing version of Drools (6.5.0.Final). I also tried adding kie-ci to the parent project, but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had many of these kie-ci warnings in my project until I found from [1] that you need to add the file jboss-all.xml with the contents of

```
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <weld xmlns="urn:jboss:weld:1.0" require-bean-descriptor="true"/>
</jboss>


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491542/deploy-kie-ci-on-wildfly-fails?rq=1
```

Comment: Where did you put the META-INF folder? I can't find it in our structure.

Comment: UPDATE: used the jboss-cli command in the attached article and it worked great. Thank you so much!